# Address of model instead value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code:

```
<% @pg.items.each do |i|%>
  <%= i.item_name %> # will display item name
  <%=  i.price_group_lines.where(price_group_id: @pg.id).take %>
<% end %>
```

In browser I see #PriceGroupLine:0x007fcc05e53598.
How do i get a value?

Comment: What shows up as ` #PriceGroupLine:0x007fcc05e53598` ?  Ie, which line from your erb template?  What that looks like is what you would get if you did `<%= pgl %>`, which i can't see in the snippet above.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my code in upper message.

Comment: BTW "i" is a really bad choice of variable name to hold the `Item` object.  `i` is usually used for an array index, by convention.  Also by convention, you should call variables descriptive names, such as the lowercase version of the model in question - `item` in this case.  Someday you might not be the only person reading your code and you don't want the other people saying "What the hell is "i" here? .... oh, it's an Item object, right".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are trying to display an entire row from the db:

```
<%=  i.price_group_lines.where(price_group_id: @pg.id).take %>
```

But you probably want to show a value from the row, like:

```
<%=  i.price_group_lines.where(price_group_id: @pg.id).take.amount %>
```

That will show the `amount` (if that attribute exists) from the `price_group_line`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! Attribute was "price" ))